# StructureLayout compiling error System.TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, structure

Hi I recently changed my StructureLayout in my code with a Layout that I used in other code but I never understand it because I got help here and I just copy pasted and addapted it to my code but now I got an error while compiling

**System.TypeLoadException : 'Could not load type 'Data' from assembly 'Recorder, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it contains an object field at offset 4 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.'**

here is my Structure Layout

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Data{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public string Title;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public ChannelData Channel;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public DateData Date;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public TimeData Begin;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public TimeData End;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct ChannelData{
    public string Title;
    public int Number;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DateData{
    public int Day;
    public int Month;
    public int Year;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct TimeData{
    public byte Hour;
    public byte Minute;
}
```

Comment: You have the same 0 field offset for every field, you should calculate the offset manually for every field, like in [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski ok .. but how do I calculate this ? 0,4,8,12,16 ?

Comment: According to data type of each structure. Why do you need `Explicit` layout instead of `Sequential`? `string` should be properly marshalled as well, if you are using it for p/invoke

Comment: like I said ... it's my second time using Layouts and the first time I never really understood it so copy pasted the example. I didn't know that I could use sequential when I use structure inside structure ... i tought that I could not do that

Comment: You already use struct inside struct, since every value type in .net is structure obviously. You can improve your understanding by reading the [specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute?view=netframework-4.8) and other documentation. Question _ I never understand it because_ is some kind off-topic here